# Headers are not been sending Basic Auth for swagger-lume

Tags: php, swagger, swagger-ui, lumen, swagger-2.0

I have Basic Auth Api in Lumen. For that Api i integrated Swagger-ui using below url : https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/SwaggerLume

To Enable custom headers in swagger ui. we done the  changes in following 2 files

**1. swagger-lume.php**

```
     'headers' => [
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Uncomment to add response headers when swagger is generated
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
         */
        /*"view" => [
        'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'
        ],*/
        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Uncomment to add request headers when swagger performs requests
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
         */
        "request" => [
    'Authorization ' => 'Basic  YWRtaW46YWRtaW4='
    ],
    ],
```

**2. Generated index.blade.php  code as follows**

```
  basicAuth=  "Basic " + btoa("admin:admin");
swaggerUi.api.clientAuthorizations.add("key", new SwaggerClient.ApiKeyAuthorization("Authorization", basicAuth, "header"));
```

But headers are not sending in request. please check the below image for reference

[image]

Please suggest, how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I defined many securityDefinitions, in annotation syntax in api file. I found issue came from json file. Removed below annotation syntax, then the headers are accepting in ajax call.

```
...,
"securityDefinitions":{
    "administrator":{
        "type":"basic",
        "description":"The administrator."
    },
    "supervisor":{
        "type":"basic",
        "description":"A supervisor."
    },
    "customer":{
        "type":"basic",
        "description":"A customer."
    }
},
...
```